# Codeigniter helpers work locally but not on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm doing a simple

```
$this->load->helper('email');
sendEmail();
```

and it loads on my local machine that is running php 5.5.12 however on my webserver that is running php 5.4.16 I get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sendEmail()
```

Is this a php version issue? Or could it be something else? Everywhere I've read I don't see any issues with running codeigniter on 5.4.16

Comment: You sure you uploaded everything correctly?

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter?

Comment: Im using version 3 of codeigniter

Comment: Hi, you need to see the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/email_helper.html), this function does not exist, this is the right `send_email($recipient, $subject, $message)`

Comment: I have that function in my helper. And it loads on my local machine but not on my webserver

Comment: If you say you have that function than maybe your helper isn't set correctly. Are you sure that your helper is extending the CI_Email library? Can you confirm that it's extending it?

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter 3 **has built-in email helper** it is deprecated and is currently only kept for backwards compatibility so CI loads own helper before then yours.

In fact, CI email helper has not a function sendEmail() so you get an error.
You should delete built-in email helper or change your helper name.

CI email helper [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/email_helper.html)

Comment: What he needs instead is the [email library](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html)

Comment: Rather than deleting overriding the `sendEmail` function would be good thing to do.